# Jump to global mark ring after jumping to register

Tags: cycling, mark-ring

In buffer B, I press <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r SPC r</kbd> to store the position of point.

I switch to buffer A and do some work. I then press <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r j r</kbd> to return to the position I saved in buffer B.

How do I get back to the position I left in buffer A? The following do not give the required result: <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd>, <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> or <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-@</kbd>.

My understanding is that <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>r j r</kbd> will push the position onto the global mark ring and that <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> will take me back there.

Comment: `C-x C-@` should work. What does happen instead?

Comment: @PhilHudson That takes me somewhere else in the current buffer.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like what you'd expect *if* "do some work" included, once or more, any of the many actions that set the mark. Each of those actions pushes another mark onto the stack (technically a ring, but stack for our current purposes). Each `C-x C-@` pops one off the stack and jumps to it. Try repeating `C-x C-@` multiple times. You should see point move to more-or-less recognizable places where you did something other than just typing, one after another.

Comment: So `C-x C-@` will not return point to where it was when I pressed `C-x r j r`? I expected that that would be the last entry in the global mark ring. Note that after jumping to the saved register position in buffer B, I don't move point. I just read what is there, and then I want to jump back to buffer A. Thinking about it now though -- the solution would be to just switch buffers with `C-x b`? :-/

Comment: A single `C-x C-@` will not *necessarily* return point to where it was. If you execute it *immediately* then it should return point to where it was. Switching buffers is neither necessary nor optimal if everything's working right, but you can certainly do that.